# How to display struct columns without truncating and select one field of the struct in polars?

Tags: python-polars

How to display struct columns without truncating and select one field of struct in polars?
I have such a df:

```
┌────────┬─────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────┐
│ status ┆ snapshot_id         ┆ data_file                         │
│ ---    ┆ ---                 ┆ ---                               │
│ i32    ┆ i64                 ┆ struct[15]                        │
╞════════╪═════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ 1      ┆ 8879697727609511654 ┆ {"file:/Users/doki/tmp/iceberg/w… │
│ 1      ┆ 8879697727609511654 ┆ {"file:/Users/doki/tmp/iceberg/w… │
└────────┴─────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────┘
```

I want to see the whole content of `data_file`, how to do?
And how to select one field of a struct just like `df.select('struct.field')`?

I tried to set FMT_STR_LEN=10000, but it didn't work.

Comment: You can use [`.struct.field()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.struct.field.html) to select fields.